# Display store location via map pin in xamarin form

Tags: google-maps, xamarin.forms

I want to expound the title. Currently we are making our thesis/project.
We have 2 platforms. Web and mobile.

In our web, we have functionality/feature that admin can insert data of store into database, example fields are name of the store, their products and the LOCATION OF that store.

I am assign in our mobile, one of the functionality is map. I have this UI

[image]

That red circle is the parameter of our location or limitation or let say NEARBY ME and the PINS assuming those are the store who subscribes in our system, that's my expected output.

This is what I've done in my tab view "map" with map.

my map xaml

```
<maps:Map  
    x:Name="myMap"
    MapType="Hybrid"
    IsShowingUser="True"
/>
```

map.xaml.cs

```
public  MapPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DisplayCurrentLocation();
  // this.AddMarkerInCurrentLocation();
}
```

```
public async void DisplayCurrentLocation()
{
    try
    {
        var request = new GeolocationRequest(GeolocationAccuracy.Medium);
        var location = await Geolocation.GetLocationAsync(request);
        if (location != null)
            
        {
           Position p = new Position(location.Latitude, location.Longitude);
          MapSpan mapSpan = MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(p, Distance.FromKilometers(.444));
           myMap.MoveToRegion(mapSpan);
       
        }                      
    
    }
    catch(FeatureNotSupportedException fnsEx)
    {

    }
    catch   
        (FeatureNotEnabledException fneEx)
    { 

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Any link's solution that are related to my post, kindly comment it and Im glad to study the article.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: the documentation shows how to display pins on the map, and there are numerous existing questions on this topic too.  Have you read them?  Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Im stuck in how to fetch the location (latlong[ maybe?]) in our web platform, the store's location and save it to the pin then display to our end in mobile

Comment: that's what `GetLocationAsync` does.  It gets the users current location.  What location are you talking about?

Comment: Hello sir, pls see the image I attach. This is what I mean. Thank you for understanding since I'm beginner to this tech.  [Visual explanation of what I've express](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIAtn.png).

Comment: Do you want to display a map with all stores near the users current location?

Comment: yes sir,I want to display the store who subscribe in our system, and I want to display it via pin. Just like the image I include in our thread.

Comment: 1) get the current user location  2) use that location to request a list of nearby stores from your server  3) use that list of locations to add pins to your map

Comment: since Im beginner sir, do  you have any link that are related to your last comments, so that I make it as a reference.

Comment: @helloSir Have you obtained the location(Latitude, Longitude) of the stores?

Comment: @ jainwei sun, nope sir but may ask sir you have idea about my problem, what should we do in our web platform, we will get the latlong then save to firebase?then I will follow the comment of sir @jason?

Comment: @helloSir One question, one post. You can post a new question about how to obtain the location of the stores in your web platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Display store location via map pin in xamarin form**

If you have obtained the location(Latitude, Longitude) of the stores, you can do this:

```
List<Location_Store> Location_Stores =new List<Location_Store>();

// Add the location of stores to List
Location_Stores.add(...);

foreach (var item in Location_Stores)            
{                
   Pin pin = new Pin                
   {                    
      Label = item.StoreName,                    
      //Address = "The city with a boardwalk",                    
      Type = PinType.Place,                    
      Position = new Position(item.Latitude,item.Longitude)               
   };                
   myMap.Pins.Add(pin);            
}
```

Location_Store.cs:

```
public class Location_Store    
  {        
    public string StoreName { get; set; }        
    public double Latitude { get; set; }        
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    ...    
  }
```

For more information about how to display location by pin in Xamarin Forms, you can refer to [Xamarin.Forms Map Pins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/pins).

Comment: thank you so much sir, I wil update here in comment section soon if how it is going cause right now, Im working another functionality of our system. Thanks to you sir because you helped me in my problem.