# Is there a way to add multiple pins to a .net Maui map in the code behind class?

Tags: .net, maps, maui, maui-community-toolkit

I am trying to download a JSON file with multiple pins. I would like to display into the map using the code behind ( I don’t like working too much with the XAML part)

I have tried several things

1. I tried doing `map.Pins = list<pin>`. But this didn't work.
2. I tried to loop my list of pins and adding one by one

   ```
    foreach(var pin in pins)
    {
        map.Pins.add(pin);
    }
   ```

This did not elevate any errors but the pins don't show on the map.

I have seen some post of people binding the data directly into XAML. In worst case, I will do it this way but I would rather do it in the code behind.

Thanks. I hope the question is clear. I am writing it on my phone, so it's hard to get the code in.

Comment: use `map.Pins.Add()`.  If the map is not centered on the region of the pin and at the appropriate zoom level you will not be able to see it.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**

> I have seen some post of people binding the data directly into xaml worst case I do it this way but I would rather do it in the code behind!

Here is the [official xaml code sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/map?view=net-maui-7.0#display-a-pin-collection):

```
<ContentPage ...
             xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps">    
    <Grid>
        ...
        <maps:Map x:Name="map"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Positions}">
            <maps:Map.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <maps:Pin Location="{Binding Location}"
                              Address="{Binding Address}"
                              Label="{Binding Description}" />
                </DataTemplate>    
            </maps:Map.ItemTemplate>
        </maps:Map>
        ...
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

The equivalent C# code is:

```
map.SetBinding(ItemsView.ItemsSourceProperty, "Positions");
map.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
{
    Pin pin = new Pin();
    pin.SetBinding(Pin.LocationProperty, "Location");
    pin.SetBinding(Pin.AddressProperty, "address");
    pin.SetBinding(Pin.LabelProperty, "Description");

    return pin;
});
```

You can refer to this: [The appearance of each item in the CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/populate-data?view=net-maui-7.0#define-item-appearance).

**Method 2**

You can see [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75077866/19902734) in another thread. For MAUI, remember to use [`Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.devices.sensors.location?view=net-maui-7.0) instead of [`Postion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.maps.position?view=xamarin-forms) which is for Forms.