# A way to auto generate pins on MAUI Map with information from a database

Tags: .net, maps, maui

I am kinda stuck on implementing something like this with MAUI limited documentation.

I am trying to think of a way to generate pins based on the info from a database.

For now, I just managed to generate multiple pins on the map but beyond that I can't think of a way to approach this issue.

As you see in the vModelMap method I am adding pins but for each pin I gotta write a new object containing that info. How would I be able to create a new object with information from database respectively from the table.

I don't want a full database solution to not put you guys to extra work, but perhaps an example to understand how could this be achieved.

MainPage.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps"
             xmlns:sensors="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Devices.Sensors;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Essentials"
             xmlns:maps1="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Maps;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Maps"
             x:Class="mauiMap.MainPage">

        <maps:Map x:Name="map" ItemsSource="{Binding Pins}">
            <x:Arguments>
                <MapSpan>
                    <x:Arguments>
                        <sensors:Location>
                            <x:Arguments>
                                <x:Double>36.9628066</x:Double>
                                <x:Double>-122.0194722</x:Double>
                            </x:Arguments>
                        </sensors:Location>
                        <x:Double>0.01</x:Double>
                        <x:Double>0.01</x:Double>
                    </x:Arguments>
                </MapSpan>
            </x:Arguments>
            <maps:Map.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <maps:Pin Location="{Binding Location}"
                              Address="{Binding Address}"
                              Label="{Binding Description}" />
                </DataTemplate>    
            </maps:Map.ItemTemplate>
        </maps:Map>
</ContentPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps;
using Microsoft.Maui.Maps;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls;
using Bumptech.Glide.Load.Model;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using static Android.Icu.Text.Transliterator;
using AndroidX.Lifecycle;

namespace mauiMap;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = new vModelMap();
    }

    public class vModelMap
    {
        public ObservableCollection<PinViewModel> Pins { get; set; }

        public vModelMap()
        {
            Pins = new ObservableCollection<PinViewModel>();

            
            Pins.Add(new PinViewModel
            {
                Location = new Location(39.9628066, -80.0194722),
                Address = "123 Main St",
                Description = "Pin 1"
            });

            Pins.Add(new PinViewModel
            {
                Location = new Location(36.9628067, -122.0194723),
                Address = "456 Elm St",
                Description = "Pin 2"
            });
        }
    }

    public class PinViewModel
    {
        public Location Location { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }


}
```

I am new to MAUI and as you can see I have learned how to bind data.

Comment: Is this a local db or a remote one?  What does your table structure look like?  There are multiple docs and sample of db queries in Xamarin and MAUI.  Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Its not clear what the problem is. You need to learn how to query a DB to get the list of objects. That’s basic DB querying; not really a question here, yet. Then, you loop over the returned objects, and create a pin for each. Which you show code to do, so you got that part. Go learn more about DB queries. Come back when you get stuck on some *specific* detail.

Comment: Write a DB query to get all the objects from your DB in form of `PinViewModel` & then add those objects to your observable collection

Comment: Thanks guys ! I will try with looping through from the db

Comment: You can check this [Display store location via map pin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75041683/display-store-location-via-map-pin-in-xamarin-form/75077866#75077866) for more information.